# Problem with Stats and Normal Distrubtion

Tags: statistics

This question came up on my homework for a beginning Statistics class. We just finished up learning how to solve Normal Distribution problems.

> Suppose the scores of students on a science test are normally
>   distributed with a mean of $523$ and a standard deviation of $121$. What
>   percentage of the students scored between $523$ and $765$ on the test?

Going over the examples we were taught, I thought this question would need the use of this equation.

> x = μ + zσ

But in the example from the class, we were given a percentage. So we could get the compliment from that and then z using a table. But here I see no percentage, and it's asking for one.

I don't think that equation works with this, and I have no idea where I'm suppose to  be going with this.

I'm more stumped than a freshly cut tree here. What am I suppose to use for this?

Comment: If X = a student score then X is normally distributed with mean 523 and standard deviation 121. Then the variable N =(X-523)/121 is also normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Now use your notes/class examples to find the probability that X is between 523 and 765 by using the table for N. The % is simply to multiply this value by 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its 47.72 percent (2 decimal places). You can do a quick estimation of this problem by using [68-95-99 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule). The value 765 is 2 standard deviation (765 = 523+ 2* 121) away from the mean (523). So within 2 standard deviation we have 95 percent (0.9545 see the link) of the value i.e between (281-765). Since you want only between (523-765) its half of it or 47.72 percent

Comment: Oh, it appears so! I guess I need to do more studying on this rule. It has been talked about I just didn't think it would apply right now. Though I am curious. If this is the quick way, what exactly would be the long way?

Comment: Since probability is area under the normal distribution curve. You could have used your graphing calculator to get the same answer. If you choose mean = 523, Standard deviation = 121, lower bound = 523 and upper bound = 765. Your graphing calculator evaluates this definite integral. Or you can use normal distribution table to do this calculation.